# How can I add an image in a specific date in xAxis in highstock?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I populate my chart but in some specifics dates I need to add a marker really close than the date in xAxis, I found some months ago a link with an example but now I cant find this link, any idea how can I do that,please, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options.

One, use the [Renderer.image](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image) to add the image [onto the chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-image-on-chart/).  The advantage here is that since you place the image with a pixel position, you can position the image off the "chart" and into the axis.

Two, add a `scatter` series with a [custom](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.symbol) image [marker](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/).  The advantage here is that you can place the images by `xy` position instead of pixel position.

Answer (score 0):

What I am looking is highstock flag, here es the documentation
            http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.flags